# How to remove value from checkbox when unchecked

Tags: php, ajax

I used the onclick method in my input field to load the function

```
<td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="load();" value="Bike">Include previous service terms</td>
```

Here is the function

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">

        function load() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open('GET','include.inc.php', true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }   

    </script>
```

However I can't figure out how to remove the value displayed when I uncheck the checkbox. I have tried answers from previously asked questions but it shows syntax error on my NetBeans

Comment: Slight suggestion, you might look into using jQuery. Makes AJAX a lot easier, in my opinion.

Comment: Cmon man, dont do that. Its not even an ajax question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provided some XHR code here I am assuming you mean how to clear the `show` element when the box is unchecked. Please correct me if this is an incorrect assumption.

Try the code below. This will clear out the elements innerHTML if the box is not checked when the load function is called.

```js
function load() {
            if(!document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked){
                return document.getElementById('show').innerHTML='';
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open('GET','include.inc.php', true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```html
<td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id='checkbox1' name="checkbox1" onclick="load();" value="Bike">Include previous service terms</td>

<div id='show'>I have text</div>
```

In the above example you can see in the console log the XHR being made when the box is checked (and failing of course) and not being made when the box is unchecked.